# Angular ngFor renders nothing if array[0] = undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

There is an array:

```
var stringArray = new Array();
stringArray[1] = 'one';
```

And ngFor renders nothing in angular when stringArray[0] = undefined.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to avoid initialising the array with falsy values like `null`?

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine. I used `ng-container` for loop with `ngFor` and `ngIf` in a `< li >`
I was able to replicate that in stackblitz here is the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a2xph9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude `undefined`, `null` and `empty` values from your template, you could simply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your data source:

```
  private source = [
    undefined, 
    null, 
    "", 
    "Hello World"
  ];

  public stringArray = source.filter(i => i);
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66377361?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image: screenshot of filtered output]